# Java transitive dependency issue with no working resolution

Tags: java, maven

I am using Maven to manage my project dependencies. My dependency tree has a conflict on package B like like:

```
A -> B (v1.4)
C -> B (v1.5)
```

It turns out that package `A` depended on a bug that was fixed in v1.5, and package `C` requires functionality from 1.5 that was not in 1.4.

How do large java projects with tons of dependencies manage these types of issues? Even if package A appeared to work on a surface level with v1.5, I still feel like it would be risky to assume in all edge cases it will work as it did before.

Note that this is a hypothetical situation, so it is not necessary to know which packages these represent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With just Maven and classic jars, there is no resulution: that's why we call it the "dependency hell" ("dll hell" was the original, note the rhyme :)

There *is*, however, a technology devoted to solving precisely this issue: OSGi. Through massively complex and convoluted classloader juggling, OSGi manages to satisfy each bundle's particular dependency requirement. Bundle A can use Bundle B v1.4, while at the same time Bundle C can use B v1.5.

OSGi has been around for more than a decade now, it seems to neither thrive nor die out; rather it is gaining adoption at a glacial pace, so ever more JARs get upgraded to OSGi bundles.

Comment: Interesting. In large projects, is it more common to see OSGi techniques or just rely on the fact that most minor updates to 3rd party libs won't have breaking changes (unintentionally)?

Comment: We mostly manage to resolve these issues by, for example, upgrading A to a version which uses B v1.5. Also, libraries almost never depend on bugs in other libraries; rather the devs of A will notify the devs of B of the bug, or even submit a patch themselves. B will then receive a minor version release (say, 1.4.12) and order will be restored. This is one of the big advantages of open source development.

Answer (score 0):

in the end only one of the dependency becomes effective in runtime, you can use `<exclude>` and `<optional>` to control transitive dependencies

---

- [`<optional>` and `<exclude>`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

Comment: Sure, but in this case I have an issue in either case (or at least I cannot be certain it won't). How do you reason about picking one over the other in this case?

Comment: pick up latest making sure your code is comptible with latest API changes

Comment: but in this case I don't control A and C, so I have no control how to verify correctness. I understand I can submit patches, run my own test suites, etc, but this becomes an intractable problem in large projects with lots of transitive dependencies

Comment: you can at last make your own build for A and C

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is a conflict on a dependency, Maven picks one version based on a **nearest-wins strategy**, meaning that whatever version is nearer in the dependency tree to your module will be selected, and all other versions will be ignored. If it happens that `v1.4` is nearer in the dependency tree, it will be selected even though it's older than `v1.5`.

To control which dependency to use, you can define a `dependencyManagement` in your module to set which version Maven should use:

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.example</groupId>
         <artifactId>packageB</artifactId>
         <version>1.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- other dependencies -->
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Or you can exclude the version that you want to ignore in the dependency that has a transitive dependency on it:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>packageA</artifactId>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>com.example</groupId>
         <artifactId>packageB</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: But how can you be certain that all of your other dependencies work with the updated library? In a large java project, I don't understand how this does not wreak havoc all over the place

Answer (score 0):

This is not a maven issue - it's a java issue. Maven simply exposes it and makes it possible to identify and manage the problem. There are many solutions: most, if not all, of them are implemented as isolated classloaders, typically in Java EE or OSGi containers.

Also: As a general rule, do not allow transitive dependencies in your project -- if you use a class, add a first-class dependency to the library it is part of. At least that way it's easy to see where your dependencies are and where your problems may reside.