# Maven dependencies hell (again)

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I am working in a maven project that declares the following maven dependencies

```
<properties>
    <httpclient.version>4.2.5</httpclient.version>
    <cf-client-lib.version>1.1.1</cf-client-lib.version>
    ....
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloudfoundry-client-lib</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
<depedencies>
```

The problem it that `cloudfoundry-client-lib` uses the version 4.3.6 of the `httpclient`. I have read about this problem as [Maven dependency hell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492566/java-transitive-dependency-issue-with-no-working-resolution/25493043#25493043). Really, I found post about [a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659425/conflicting-library-version-in-a-java-maven-project) (using the same example).

I checked the problem using `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`as it was indicated [official documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) :

```
[INFO] +- org.cloudfoundry:cloudfoundry-client-lib:jar:1.1.1:compileRELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.5.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.5:compile - version managed from 4.3.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.2.5:compile)
```

I have read about the possible solutions described above [[S1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659425/conflicting-library-version-in-a-java-maven-project) [[S2]](http://www.martin-toshev.com/index.php/software-engineering/tips-and-tricks/82-solving-the-jar-hell-problem-in-maven) but I think I have to update my project to the latest library version (`4.3.6`) (and then, I could use [dependencyConvergence plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html)). However, could I find an easier **and temporal** solution for continuing the current development?

Comment: Do you have a compelling reason not to move up to the new version of httpclient?  If you do, then your option is to _try_ to have maven exclude the transitive dependency on httpclient 4.3.6.  Generally this is a bad idea since presumably the cloudfoundry people have that dependency for a reason, but you might get lucky that it's a drop-in-replacement sort of thing.  Take a look at the [maven docs on how to do this here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

Comment: Is the `httpclient` really directly used by your project or is it only part of pom based on the usage transitively?

Comment: Thx for your replies. cf-client needs the httpclient v4.3.X and the project that I am developing need the 4.2.5. I tried to use the latest version in my project, but it is not a direct step, I need to carry out a migration process (I think, it is the way).

Comment: This is not a Maven problem but a problem in your project, that Maven puts to light. How do intend for things to work if your project requires `httpclient` in two different versions (it's not like you can load selectively a class from a library in one version or another) ? Apart from being lucky (as @David suggested), this won't work directly and you will need to migrate your project to use the newer version of `httpclient`.

Comment: I am agree with you, @Tunaki. As I have mentioned in my ask I think it is the best option :) I am working on this task.